# "TypeError :super() takes at least 1 argument (0 given) " how to solve this i have used argument as a super class name but it didn't worked

Tags: python

```
students = []

class Student:
    school_name = 'Maharshi Science school'

    def __init__(self,name,student_id=336):
        self.name = name
        self.student_id= student_id
        students.append(self)

    def __str__(self):
        return "student: " + self.name

    def get_name_capitalize(self):
        return self.name.capitalize()

    def get_school_name(self):
        return self.school_name


class HighschoolStudent(Student):

    school_name = 'Maharshi High School'

    def get_school_name(self):
        return "This is a high school student"

    def get_name_capitalize(self):
        original_value = super().get_name_capitalize()
        return original_value + "-HighschoolStudent"

chirag = HighschoolStudent('chirag')
print(chirag.get_name_capitalize())
```

Comment: This is not a nice question according to this site rules, because it only contains code with no context. The title contains too much information which should have been posted in body, and you failed to declare the Python version that you use (and it matters here). As a new user, you really should read [ask] to be able to ask much better questions later :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error will only occur if you are using Python 2. To fix this, replace

```
super().get_name_capitalize()
```

with

```
super(HighschoolStudent, self).get_name_capitalize()
```

If you upgrade to Python 3, your code should work fine.

Answer (score 0):

You are getting the error due to Python 2. Please try the below code:

```
students = []

class Student(object):

    school_name = 'Maharshi Science school'

    def __init__(self,name,student_id=336):
        self.name = name
        self.student_id= student_id
        students.append(self)

    def __str__(self):
        return "student: " + self.name

    def get_name_capitalize(self):
        return self.name.capitalize()

    def get_school_name(self):
        return self.school_name

class HighschoolStudent(Student):

    school_name = 'Maharshi High School'

    def get_school_name(self):
        return "This is a high school student"

    def get_name_capitalize(self):
        original_value = super(HighschoolStudent, self).get_name_capitalize()
        return original_value + "-HighschoolStudent"


chirag = HighschoolStudent('chirag')

print(chirag.get_name_capitalize())
```

Output:
`Chirag-HighschoolStudent`

There are two changes in this:

- `class Student` --> `class Student(object)`
- Passing your class name as input in super as mandated by Python 2